# Rails 3 Form Element's id attr not unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What I use rails form helpers to build a form, input elements in that form have id attributes so they can match with their labels. The problem is this id is the something like `person_first_name` and not `person_first_name_#{person.id}` meaning if I have more than one form of the same type on the same page unexpected things can happen.

A perfect example of this is using jquery-ui datepicker. I have a series of forms all containing a text_field element wrapped in a div with the class datepicker. I apply the datepicker like this (in document ready) `$('.datepicker input').datepicker(options)` and guess what, every one of these elements, although has a seemingly working datepicker (click on input, datepicker appears), although when a date is selected in any of these datepickers only the first element on the page (of that element type, ex. input id=published_on) gets updated with the value.

Any suggestions on getting rails to output more unique element id's or make datepicker not use the id attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Haml
= form_for @model do |f|
  .field
    = f.label :field_name
    = f.text_field :field_name
```

When using the above example, ids are rendered as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily customize the id of your input.

```
text_field(:person, :first_name, :id => "person_first_name_#{person.id}")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I would like a cleaner solution though as this breaks the label functionality (rails doesn't detect the inputs new id, so the label's :for attr is still "person_first_name" and not "person_first_name_#{person.id}").

Comment: You can do: label(:person, : first_name, "First Name", :value => person.id)
  # => <label for="person_first_name_4">First name</label>

Answer (score 0):

One would think that if you set the ID of the form to say :id => "edit_person_#{person.id}" that this ID would cascade downwards into the label and field logic. From what I can see, there's too much auto-magic in the way of adding an eloquent custom solution.